# How to implement two highcharts response related with same trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a new requirement, that one page contains several highcharts.
And when I move mouse on one highchart, tooltips will be shown, and a guideline also will be shown. Maybe it calls trackball. In the same time, another highchart in this page, will also show its tooltips and guideline(trackball).
Just like this, `http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/nhVbs/`, 
but this is in one series.
Any one do such job before can give me some advise?

I only got one example for similar work.

```
http://vikinghammer.com/2012/02/02/connecting-highcharts-and-jqgrid-with-trigger-and-bind/
```

But not understand how he implement it.

When move the mouse to one line chart, two charts will all show the guidelines and tooltips.
Like this demonstrate.

[image]

Comment: What kind of charts you need to combine, because in your example it is connected. Maybe better is use a few panes (in single chart) instead of few one.

Comment: agree - example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/KMA55/

Comment: Thanks Sebastin and jlbriggs.
I know how to use this in one chart with tooltip crosshairs.
But I have different line charts with different data sources, and they share same x-axis(weekly date). (It will show the relationship between them with time perspecitive.)
And it seems better to separate them into independent line charts. Any one have better idea to do such things?

Comment: You can use two xAxis / two yAxis panes.